# how can I dynamically add methods to a class in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to add a method to a class from outside of class, in format of function pointer or another format, as a native method.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do? Adding a function is not in inteself helpfull because who and how do you call it?

Comment: You could have a list of `std::function` in your class, but could you be a little more specific ?

Comment: for example, we can overload a method, externally and call it with new signature, dunamically.

Comment: @v.mafi, that's now how overloading works. You should try to explain what you want to do.

Comment: i want to add a static method to all classes for logging with log4cxx. where class name is important for logger and logger will be specfic for that class.

Comment: It seems that template function taking the class in parameter can do the job...

Comment: how can I send class name to template function body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement your logging facility like this, without template functions and make use of the `log4cxx::LoggerPtr` smart pointer.

Regarding the class name:
Afaik there is no compiler independent way to access the class name of a static class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class CMyClass
{
    public:

    // Default logger:
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr logger(log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("com.foo"));

    // You have to adapt this for every of your static classes:
    const char* classname() { return "CMyClass";}

    static void printClassName()
    {
        // For example:
        LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, classname())
    }

    // Point to a new logger object by reassigning the logger smart pointer.
    static void setLogger(const log4cxx::LoggerPtr &l)
    {
        logger = l;
    }    
};
```