# Is it possible to truncate C preprocessor identifiers?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

In C, with `#define`, we can use the token pasting operator `##` to concatenate an identifier with some other text.

Is it possible to do the reverse as seen in the example below?

```cpp
#define millimeter
//truncate to milli
//convert to millisecond
```

I am specifically trying to use this for function name generation, so a call to a non-existent function `millimeter()` can generate code containing `millisecond`.

The previous paragraph is an example of how I would use this. I have included it for context, but I am not sure if that is possible even if the identifier can be truncated. If you can link related questions for this part, that would be helpful.

**Edit:**
Most of you are right, this is definitely an XY issue. What I was hoping was that if someone tries to use the function `millisecond()`, it would auto-generate code which needed to contain `millimeter()`.

I realize this isn't possible, so now I have a macro like `#define TIME_FUNC_DEFINE(unit) function_definition`. It is used like `TIME_FUNC_DEFINE(millis)` which will create both `millisecond` and `millimeter` as needed.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve here, because what you're advocating is best described as *dark sorcery*. C and C++ are built on the foundation of programmers expressing *specifically* what they want to have happen, and there should be no "magic" going on.

Comment: see also https://xyproblem.info.

Comment: Made worse by **meter** and **second** measuring quite different things.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you mean with talk of "a call to a non-existent function". Can you maybe give a before-and-after example of what a given block of code should look like assuming you got your preprocessing set up correctly?

Comment: @WeatherVane Don't get me started on parsecs!

Comment: No.   When it occurs in code, `millimeter` is treated as a single token by the preprocessor however it is formed (e.g. by token pasting done by other macros) and - unless it participates in token pasting or stringification - is replaced immediately with its expansion (which, in your example, is nothing).  The preprocessor can't split tokens like you want, since they are expanded to their definition.

Comment: Are you looking to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33889181/102937)?

Comment: You could approach it from the other direction: `#define` your prefixes and your units separately, and then concat them to form other tokens.

Comment: One way is to make the non-existent function exist :-)  `int millimeter() { return millisecond(); }`

Comment: I don't understand what your actual problem is, but perhaps you can pass `(milli, meter)` instead of `millimeter`. Passing `( , meter)` may not be legal then, depending on how strict your preprocessor is implemented, though.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about function definitions.

Comment: I hope to never encounter such source code. In a code review I would reject it as much as possible. Source code is supposed to make the intent of the programmer crystal clear, unambiguous, non-magical, to grasp at first sight. As tadman asks, please [edit] your question and add _why at all_ you need this magic. To me it looks like bad architecture or design or none at all.

Comment: Let me see if I follow. Your example snags the first five characters from `millimeter`, dropping the last five, then appends `seconds`. So if you were instead given `nanoparsec` (also ten characters), you should end up with `nanopseconds`? *(Sometimes a better definition of a goal leads to a better solution. Details matter.)*

Comment: @JaMiT Use would be much more restricted. So only `nanometer` would be used not `nano parsec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of input to the C preprocessor are (preprocessing) tokens such as identifiers, operators, and string literals.  Tokens are atomic as far as the preprocessor is concerned -- it has no mechanism for dividing them into pieces or for operating in any other way on partial tokens.

Under some circumstances, you can use macro substitution to emulate truncation of a pre-selected (by you) set of specific tokens that have the form of identifiers or keywords, but this is not generalizable.

> I am specifically trying to use this for function name generation

Where this sort of thing is done, it is generally done by pasting tokens together, not truncating them.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible code adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355243/1046249

TRUNCATE(x) will do the reverse of paste by truncating a predefined set of tokens. Then CAT(x,y) pastes y onto the end of x so CAT(TRUNCATE(millimeter),second)() becomes millisecond().

I have no idea why you would ever want to do this.

```
#define TRUNCATE_millimeter  milli
#define TRUNCATE_milligram   milli

#define TRUNCATE(s) TRUNCATE_ ## s

#define _CAT(x,y) x ## y
#define CAT(x,y) _CAT(x,y)

int millisecond() {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    CAT(TRUNCATE(millimeter), second)();
    CAT(TRUNCATE(milligram), second)();

    return 0;
}
```